# Spray on AWS Bind to localhost/127.0.0.1:80 failed

Tags: spray, spray-dsl

I have set up everything for spray on my AWS instance.

I am also able to run the sample spray-template successfully.

But the issue is spray-template uses port 8080 to bind when I change port from 8080 to 80.

I am facing below mentioned error.

```
Bind to localhost/127.0.0.1:80 failed
```

Below is line from my Boot.Scala file

```
IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = "localhost", port = 8080
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you start spray process with root or ordinary user? Ports below 1024 requires root permission to bind.

Comment: Hey dude thanks you are right it was due to root permission.